# Tracing through Linked List code

Tags: c, linked-list

Here is a linked list where pList points to the node containing the value 3

```
pList
  |
  3       7       6       1       2       8       4      5    ->     NULL
```

Given the following code, redraw the list showing the changes to the list after the following code is executed.

```
pCur = pList;
while(pCur->next->next != NULL)
   pCur = pCur->next;
pCur->next->next = pList;
pList = pCur -> next;
pCur -> next = NULL;
pCur = NULL;
```

Here is my interpretation of what is happening:
    pCur = pList (pCur = pList)
      |
      3       7       6       1       2       8       4      5    ->     NULL

```
pList    pCur  (pCur = pCur->next)
  |       |
  3       7       6       1       2       8       4      5    ->     NULL

         pCur           PList (pCur->next->next = pList)
          |               |
  3       7       6       1       2       8       4      5    ->     NULL

         pCur   pList       (pList = pCur->next)
          |       |
  3       7       6       1       2       8       4      5    ->     NULL


                     (pCur->next = NULL)
  3       7       6       1       2       8    -> NULL
```

I don't believe this is correct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know whether that's right or not.  If you don't believe that you have it correct, you could always step through it in a debugger, to see what it *actually* does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it actually does is this:

We start with the following:

```
pCur = pList (pCur = pList)
  |
  3       7       6       1       2       8       4      5    ->     NULL
```

We then move pCur one forward while pCur->next->next != NULL, so we end up with

```
pList                                           pCur
  |                                               |
  3       7       6       1       2       8       4      5    ->     NULL
```

Then we attach the head of the list to the tail

```
pList                                           pCur          pList (again)
  |                                               |             |
  3       7       6       1       2       8       4      5      3      7 ....
```

This gives us an infinitely circular list.

We then move pList to point to pCur->next

```
                                                pCur   pList      
                                                  |      |       
  3       7       6       1       2       8       4      5      3      7 ....
```

If we move this over so that pList is first (which we can do, as it's infinitely circular):

```
pList                                                   pCur   pList (again)
  |                                                       |      | 
  5       3       7       6       1       2       8       4      5      3      7 ....
```

We finally say that what follows pCur is NULL, giving us:

```
pList                                                   pCur   
  |                                                       |      
  5       3       7       6       1       2       8       4    ->     NULL
```

As you can see, what this does is move the last element of the list up to the front.

Answer (score 0):

You're omitting the links, so you can't show the effect of `pCur->next = NULL`. Also, `pCur->next->next = pList` sets `pCur`, not `pList`.

It's pretty easy to make these drawing programmatically:

```
void print_list(Link const *pCur, Link const *pList)
{
    Link const *p;

    printf("pCur -> ");
    for (p = pCur; p != NULL && p != pList; p = p->next)
        printf("%d -> ", p->data);
    puts(p == NULL ? "NULL" : "pList");

    printf("pList -> ");
    for (p = pList; p != NULL && p != pCur; p = p->next)
        printf("%d -> ", p->data);
    puts(p == NULL ? "NULL" : "pCur");
}
```